# Why my values are not being added to global ArrayList from the inner class

Tags: java, android

I get data from server and I am creating the object of class `QuizFormat` for each time the loop executes. I have a global `ArrayList` declared in which I am trying to add these objects. I am doing this task in a separate method `getTest()` which has inner class and it is extending the `AsyncTask` class, as the background task of fetching the data is carried out in it. The problem is, the objects are not being added to the list. I tried creating a separate method to add objects by passing them as parameters, but not a luck. How can i fix this? Here is the code I am using.
`QuizFormat`, a basic class with constructor, getters and setters:

```java
public class QuizFormat {
    int id;
    String question;
    String[] options;
    String answer;

    public QuizFormat(int id, String question, String[] options, String answer) {
        this.id = id;
        this.question = question;
        this.options = options;
        this.answer = answer;
    }
    //getters and setters below
    ...
    ...
}
```

Following is the `TestActivity` class, in which i am doing all the above described task:

```java
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     ArrayList<QuizFormat> quizFormatList; //Global ArrayList
      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        
        quizFormatList = new ArrayList<QuizFormat>(); // Initializing ArrayList
        getTest(); //call to the method to fetch and add elements
        
        //checking final size
        Log.i("size","ArrayList: "+ quizFormatList.size());
        try {
            for (QuizFormat qf: quizFormatList) {
                Log.i("que",qf.getQuestion());
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void getTest(){
        class FetchData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                
                for (int i=0; i<testArray.length(); i++){
                    //Parsing JSON data here, skipping that part
                    
                    String[] options = new String[4];
                    options[0] = optionsObj.getString("opt1");
                    options[1] = optionsObj.getString("opt2");
                    options[2] = optionsObj.getString("opt3");
                    options[3] = optionsObj.getString("opt4");

                    int que_id = testObj.getInt("que_id");
                    String question = testObj.getString("question");
                    String answer = testObj.getString("answer");
                    
                    //Adding to ArrayList
                    quizFormatList.add(new QuizFormat(que_id, question, options, answer));
                }
                //checking ArrayList size
                Log.i("quizFormatList", "size: "+quizFormatList.size());
            }
        }
        //Executing class
        FetchData fd = new FetchData();
        fd.execute();
    }
}
```

Following is the logcat output.
This is the size in counted from inner class 'FetchData'

```
I/quizFormatList: size: 5
```

and the following one is the size counted in `onCreate()` method after calling `getTest()`, as shown in the code above.

```
I/size: ArrayList: 0
```

How can i get that data in the list, and how to access it? Help needed.

Comment: probably because of the synchronisity. Have you debugged your code, to check in which order everything executes?

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, I just checked and wondering that the full `onCreate()` method executed first and the method `getTest()` is executing later, thats why it might be causing. But any solution for that?

Comment: Indeed. You started your asynctask at the end of onCreate. And as doInBackground runs in a different thread onCreate has long ended before doInBackground has even started But all what you do in onPostExecute is ok. But... i see no doInBAckground...

Comment: @blackapps But i want to use the objects in that list to do further task. Can I access them from `onCreate()` method? Any solution?

Comment: @blackapps I am sending an API request in `doInBackground()` method, just not shown here cause it doesn't relate with this question and it is working fine.

Comment: Ok. If you wanna use the list than do it in onPostExecute. You can in onPostExecute  just call a function in your activity that does the work. Put all code after `//checking final size` in a function checkSize() and call it in onPostExecute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic problem of async vs sync behavior. What's happening here is that you are calling the method `getTest` which is asynchronous and accessing right after that `quizFormatList`. The problem is that you access `quizFormatList` before `getTest` has a chance to populate it. Unfortunately, this cannot be done like that and also, sometimes it might work, and sometimes it might not.

There are several solutions for this, let me try and provide one that doesn't require too many changes to what you have now. First, we want the async task to actually notify the main activity when it's done with its work. We will do this with a callback:

```
interface OnAsyncWorkDoneCallback {
  void asyncWorkDone(List<QuizFormat> quizFormatList);
}

class FetchData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
  private final List<QuizFormat> quizFormatList = new ArrayList<>();
  private final OnAsyncWorkDoneCallback callback;

  public FetchData(OnAsyncWorkDoneCallback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    // Do exactly what you were doing before and populate the field quizFormat

    callback.asyncWorkDone(quizFormatList);
  }
}
```

So what we have is an async task that requires now a callback to be created and once it's done it'll call this callback with the correct results for `quizFormatList`.

Here's how you use it from the activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    new FetchData((results) -> {
        // do whatever you need to do with results
    }).execute();
  }   
}
```

---

The code above will hopefully work and serve your needs, but I have to say that using async tasks on android is considered dangerous and highly discouraged. This topic is another whole answer by itself and I didn't want to address it right now, since your problem is not necessarily specific to async tasks, but to race conditions in an asynchronous environment. However, you can see that if the main activity gets destroyed (the phone rotates, i.e.) the callback passed to the currently running async task will belong to a destroyed activity and depending on what you do with the results it might end up trying to access things it can no longer access. This is just one of the issues with this approach. You can read online about all of it, there's more than enough information on it, but here's a really good [post](https://blog.danlew.net/2014/06/21/the-hidden-pitfalls-of-asynctask/) by Dan Lew.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful information. Well, I have to look for another approach as this might break the intended task in case of device rotation. But appreciate your help.